# How to access *args variable name(s) in __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

How do I access *args variable name(s) in `__init__` method?

E.g.

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # How to access *args variable names here?
        # In this example: foo, bar
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        super().__init__(foo, bar)
```

Comment: That's not even a meaningful concept.  `*args`, like any other list, contains nothing but *values*.  There's no guarantee that those values even came from variables, anyway - they could just as easily have been literals, or expressions.

Comment: This is possible in a different context. For example, a functools-wrapped wrapper can access wrapped *args variable names like so: `func.__code__.co_varnames`

Comment: *args and *kargs: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/args-kwargs-python/.  args is for values only, kargs is for key => value.

Comment: You can't. *Variables* don't get passed to functions, *objects* do. In general, you should *never have to care what the names of variables referring to your objects are*. That is usually a sign of a broken design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by OP's comment, maybe you could do something like

```py
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.child_varnames = type(self).__init__.__code__.co_varnames[1:]

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        super().__init__(foo, bar)
```

In my tests, I get

```
>>> c = Child(1, 2)
>>> c.child_varnames
('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: Yep - this did the trick. Looking to build an API wrapper where a user may pass a kwarg as an arg. Thanks